# Pandas select last row value grater than

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe

```
a = {'Price': [10, 15, 5, 25, 30], 'Total': [10000, 12000, 15000, 14000, 0],
     'WAP': [10, 10.83, 9.66, 1, 1]}
a = pd.DataFrame(a)
print (a)
```

I am looking to create a new column which says if a['WAP'] == 1, then look at a['WAP'] and return previous value in the column which isn't 1.

So in this instance I want to create a new column with values,

```
new = [10, 10.83, 9.66, 9.66, 9.66]
```

I have tried iterating through the column but only able to change the first 1 into a 9.66

```
aw = []

for i in range(len(a)):
    if a.loc[i, 'WAP'] == 1:
        aw.append(a.loc[i-1, 'WAP'])
    else:
        aw.append(a.loc[i, 'WAP'])

print (aw)
```

Comment: Whould you like to add the entries of new to the existing list in the directory entry, or do you want to add the list to the entry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution:

```
for i, row in a.iterrows():
    if row['WAP'] == 1:
        a.loc[i, 'WAP'] = a.loc[i-1, 'WAP']
    else:
        a.loc[i, 'WAP'] = a.loc[i,'WAP']  
print (a)

   Price  Total    WAP
0     10  10000  10.00
1     15  12000  10.83
2      5  15000   9.66
3     25  14000   9.66
4     30      0   9.66
```

The iterative nature of the calculation where the inputs depend on results of previous steps complicates vectorization. You could perhaps use `apply` with a function that does the same calculation as the loop, but behind the scenes this would also be a loop.

Another better solution is replace `1` by `NaN` with [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) and then [`ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ffill.html) previous value:

```
a.WAP = a.WAP.mask(a.WAP == 1).ffill()
print (a)
   Price  Total    WAP
0     10  10000  10.00
1     15  12000  10.83
2      5  15000   9.66
3     25  14000   9.66
4     30      0   9.66
```

Solution with [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html):

```
a.WAP = a.WAP.replace({1:np.nan}).ffill()
print (a)
   Price  Total    WAP
0     10  10000  10.00
1     15  12000  10.83
2      5  15000   9.66
3     25  14000   9.66
4     30      0   9.66
```